# How I can use a django variable in if statement of django template into a javascript string variable

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

I want to add a div to my page using a javascript variable. This div must take a class right or left ,but my if condition doesn't work in this variable, And it works if I try it without javascript.

This is my view :

```
def chat(request,sender_id,receiver_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.profile == 'C' or request.user.profile == 'A':
            user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).get()
            receiver_user = User.objects.filter(id=receiver_id).get()
            if request.user.profile == 'A':
                chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id) | Q(receiver_id=sender_id)).all()
            elif request.user.profile == 'C':
                chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id,receiver_id=receiver_id) | Q(sender_id=receiver_id,receiver_id=sender_id))

            context = {
                'user': user,
                'chat': chat,
                'receiver_user': receiver_user,
            }
            return render(request,'chat/chat.html',context)
    return render(request, 'Login/logout.html')
```

And this is my javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : "{% url 'getMessages' request.user.id receiver_user.id %}",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#display").empty();
                    for (var key in response.chat)
                    {
                        var temp='<div class="msg-box {% if request.user.id == chat.sender_id %} right {% else %} left {% endif %}">\
                            <div class="details">\
                                <p class="msg">'+response.chat[key].message+'</p>\
                                <p class="date">'+response.chat[key].msg_time+'</p></div></div>';
                        $("#display").append(temp);
                    }
                },
                error: function(response){
                    console.log('An error occured')
                }
            });
        },100);
    });
```

And this my models.py :

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=100000)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='sender')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='receiver')
    msg_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['msg_time']
```

Comment: could you share your model Chat and message ?

Comment: I update the question and add the models

Comment: i already posted my answer tried it.

Comment: I try it but don't work. Thanks

Comment: which error did you got ?

Comment: It works I just make a mistake by puting the code of javascript in "partial_msg.html". And I must put this code in my "index.html". Thanks !

Comment: do not forget to accept the answer if it helps you to help others that will have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so good in js so i will use partial html to answer your question.

1. in your template create a html file (partial_msg.html):

   ```
    def getMessages(request, sender_id, receiver_id):
        if request.user.profile == 'A':
            chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id) | Q(receiver_id=sender_id)).all()
        elif request.user.profile == 'C':
            chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id,receiver_id=receiver_id) | Q(sender_id=receiver_id,receiver_id=sender_id))
        return render(request,'partial_msg.html',{'chats':chat}) #new
   ```

2)partial_msg.html (just this without the head)

```
{% for chat in chats %}
<div class="msg-box {% if request.user.id == chat.sender_id %} right {% else %} left {% endif %}">
               <div class="details">
                <p class="msg">{{ chat.message }}</p>
                <p class="date">{{ chat.msg_time }}</p>
               </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

3. call your javascript

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : "{% url 'getMessages' request.user.id receiver_user.id %}",
                success: function(response){

                    $("#display").empty();

                    $("#display").append(response);

                },
                error: function(response){
                    console.log('An error occured')
                }
            });
        },1000);
    });
   ```

Note: This is just an idea how you can achieve it using django.